# android AsyncTask is blocked by phone call?

Tags: android

My `AsyncTask` class runs fine if my app is in background but if I answer a phone call, it will stop running. As soon as I hang up, I starting seeing its activity again. It communicates between my app and my database. How can I keep this background process running all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    // do your stuff here
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    // do your stuff here
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    // A call is dialing, active or on hold
                    // do your stuff here
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  class is not intented to be running on the background always, instead you should use  [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).
Also you dont have to have a live communication always with your database,you can use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

Hope this help you.